# How to connect to Android Virtual Devices on OSX host from Docker container

Tags: docker

The `OSX` host is running 4 `Android Virtual Devices`.

I initialize the `Docker` container with

```
docker run -P --network="host" -it -v ${HOME}/git/test-client-lua:/\
test-client docker-dev.sla-ptt.com:5000/dispatch-test:latest bash
```

I use the `-P` argument to expose all docker ports to random ports on the host, however when I run `adb devices` in the container there are no devices available, but when I run `adb devices` from the host, there are 4 devices available

```
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
emulator-5558   device
emulator-5560   device
```

I understand there is some kind of virutal Linux machine on the OSX host which runs the container, so I suspect this is creating the issue, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

I want to be able to interact with the virtual devices from the container using `adb`.

**edit**

By the way, the `adb` version of the the `adb` on the host and the container are identical, and the `adb` server is running on the host when I run the command `adb devices` from the container.

Comment: Not sure, but try `adb kill-server` on host before start the container, and add `--privileged` when start container, see if ok on mac?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to instrument the AVDs is to SSH from the container into the host machine.

```
# from container
ssh <user-name>@<host-ethernet-address>
```

The container appears to have its own public key. I'm not sure if it's static or not.